# textField Editing Changed not reacting fast enough (Asynchronous calls)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitextfield

I have a textfield that queries a firebase database for existing users and then display a UIImage according to if the user is available or not. The problem is that once the async code loads, the textfield doesn't react on changed value.

example. If i type 12345 as a username, i don't query the database. Everything ok. If i add a 6 it queries firebase and it shows me the user is free. if i press backspace and have 12345 the textFieldChanged is triggered again, and database is not queried. All OK.

but the problem is, when i have 12345, and i type 6 and very fast back so i have 12345, the query is running and shows me the available icon (because the back was pressed very fast). Is this because of the Simulator or is it a real problem and can i be fixed easily ?

my code:

```
 @IBAction func textFieldChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
        if let username = usernameInputText.text, username.count > 5 {
            checkIfUserExists(username: username) { doesExist in    //(2)
                if doesExist! {
                    self.completeSignupButton.isEnabled = false
                    self.ifAvailableImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Close")
                } else {
                    self.completeSignupButton.isEnabled = true
                    self.ifAvailableImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Check")
                }
            }
        } else {
            ifAvailableImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Close")
            self.completeSignupButton.isEnabled = false
        }
}

func checkIfUserExists(username: String, completion: @escaping (Bool?) -> Void) {
    spinner.startAnimating()
    self.ifAvailableImageView.image = nil
    let docRef = db.collection("users").document(username)
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if error != nil {
            self.spinner.stopAnimating()
            completion(nil)
        } else {
            self.spinner.stopAnimating()
            if let document = document {
                if document.exists {
                    completion(true)
                } else {
                    completion(false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just compare the **username** being processed with the **current text** in the text field and not process the result if it not the same because you only want to process the latest one.

```
@IBAction func textFieldChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
        if let username = usernameInputText.text, username.count > 5 {
            checkIfUserExists(username: username) { doesExist in    //(2)
                // Check if current text and the completion being processed are for the same username
                if username != sender.text {
                    return                    
                }
                if doesExist! {
                    self.completeSignupButton.isEnabled = false
                    self.ifAvailableImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Close")
                } else {
                    self.completeSignupButton.isEnabled = true
                    self.ifAvailableImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Check")
                }
            }
        } else {
            ifAvailableImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Close")
            self.completeSignupButton.isEnabled = false
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing me to the right direction :) The loading indicator is there: 
spinner.startAnimating() and self.spinner.stopAnimating()

Comment: @BjornMorrhaye ah my bad. I did not read that other function properly.

Comment: still checking :)